# Problema al generar APK in react-native Could not find method android()

Tags: android, react-native

soy nuevo en react-native y acabo de desarrollar un pequeño demo pero al intentar generar la APK siguiendo la [documentacion oficial de react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) me arroja el siguiente error "Could not find method android() for arguments" (dejare mas abajo una foto con el error completo), he seguido los pasos al pie de la letra, he investigue en diferente post pero no doy con el error

Error que muestra la consola
[image: Error que muestra la consola]

Configuracion del archivo build.gradle
[image: Configuracion del archivo build.gradle]

Comment: A mi me ha pasado algo similar, para generar la apk tuve que utilizar Android Studio, me lo genero sin ningún problema.